# Docker shared volume not working in MacOs

Tags: macos, docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I have a docker-compose.yml file. It works fine in Windows 10 but whenever I try to run that in MacOs it doesnt work especially the shared volume.

Here is the content of my docker-compose.yml file and directory structure

```
version: '3'
services:
  database:
    image: mongo
    container_name: pcore-database
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'
  node-server:
    image: node
    container_name: pcore-node-server
    volumes:
      - ./node-services :/usr/app/node-services
    working_dir: /usr/app/node-services
    command: npm run dev
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    links:
      - database
      - nginx-server
    depends_on:
      - database
  apache-server:
    image: webdevops/php-apache
    container_name: pcore-apache-server
    working_dir: /app
    volumes:
      - ./php-services :/app
    ports:
      - '8000:80'
```

Check the **node-server** service and **nginx-server**

Now when i run command **docker-compose up** it creates additional directories with same name and throws error.

Check the error and additional directories it created.
[image]

I dont know whats going on. Its working fine in windows 10 but in MacOs it creates additional directories and does not share the volumes. Can someone guid me?

Comment: please post code (as text), not images.

Comment: Please reduce your `docker-compose.yml` file to a minimum necessary to demonstrate the issue, paste that _as text_ in your question, and delete the screenshots of your IDE.  If you’re trying to bind-mount your local source tree over a Node image, there have been several recent SO questions about this causing problems (with the `node_modules` tree, in Kubernetes, ...) and I’d suggest not doing that: develop your application locally and package it in Docker as a separate step.

Comment: @Ammar I have updated the question. Please check.

Comment: @DavidMaze I can not build the image eveytime I install npm module while development. That is why I am using a shared volume.

Comment: What do u mean by "it creates additional directories"? can you share your folder structure with the way you ran the `docker-compose up` and from which folder you ran that?

Comment: @Ntwobike i run it from project root directory where docker-compose.yml file exist.
After running it creates additional node-services and php-services file.
I dont understand how come 2 folders with same name exist (you can check in image above)